# Sonarqube-8.6.1.40680 unable to connect to AWS Aurora Postgresql Serverless

Tags: sonarqube

Default installation of SonarQube is unable to connect to AWS Aurora PostgreSql Serverless database.

Below is the configuration in SONARQUBE_HOME/conf/sonar.properties

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://<host>:5432/sonarqube
sonar.jdbc.username=<postgresql-username>
sonar.jdbc.password=<postgresql-password>
```

Fails with exception in SONARQUBE_HOME/logs/web.log that its unable to connect to database.

Answer (score 0):

Had to download latest postgresql jdbc jar for Postgredatabase engine version 9.6.3

Following command was used to identify the database engine version:

```
aws rds describe-db-engine-versions --engine aurora-postgresql --output text --region us-east-1
```

Commands used to download latest jdbc jar follows:

```
cd /data/sonarqube/lib/jdbc/postgresql
sudo mv  postgresql-42.2.17.jar postgresql-42.2.17.jar_backup
wget https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.2.19.jar
sudo chown sonar:sonar postgresql-42.2.19.jar
sudo chmod 775 postgresql-42.2.19.jar
```